# Scala implicit resolution different for AnyVal?

Tags: scala, implicit

I am defining implicits in companion objects that get resolved for all types except AnyVals such as Long and Double etc. I am not exactly sure why it is the case? Are there different resolution rules for AnyVals?

```
class X(val i:Int) {
  def add[T](implicit x:SomeType[T])=println(x)
}
object X {
  implicit def xx = XType
  implicit def ll = LType
  implicit def dd = DType
}

object Console {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    new X(3).add[X] // works fine
    new X(3).add[Long] // error Error:(16, 16) could not find implicit value for parameter x: com.x.SomeType[Long]
    new X(3).add[Double] // error Error:(16, 16) could not find implicit value for parameter x: com.x.SomeType[Double]
  }
}

sealed trait SomeType[T]

case object XType extends SomeType[X]
case object LType extends SomeType[Long]
case object DType extends SomeType[Double]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know how to resolve these two implicits within `object X`:

```
implicit def ll = LType
implicit def dd = DType
```

Calling `new X(3).add[X]` is able to resolve a `SomeType[X]` because when looking for an implicit `SomeType[X]`, the compiler will look within the companion object of `X` (among other places, see [Where does Scala look for implicits?](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html)), and it finds it as `implicit def xx = XType`.

For `SomeType[Long]`, the compiler can't find the implicit in scope, nor it is available within the companion objects of `SomeType` or `Long`, so it fails. `SomeType[Double]` fails for the same reason.

If you `import X._` within `Console` it will work, because that would bring all of the implicits within scope. If you want to provide default implicit instances of `SomeType`s for different types, it would be best to place them within the companion of `SomeType`.

```
class X(val i:Int) {
  def add[T](implicit x: SomeType[T]) = println(x)
}

sealed trait SomeType[T]

object SomeType {
  implicit case object XType extends SomeType[X]
  implicit case object LType extends SomeType[Long]
  implicit case object DType extends SomeType[Double]
}
```

The following will always work now, no matter where you call them:

```
scala> new X(3).add[X]
XType

scala> new X(3).add[Long]
LType

scala> new X(3).add[Double]
DType
```

In short, it has nothing to do with `AnyVal`. You could have added a `SomeType[String]` alongside the others and had the same issue. The difference was that you were treating `X` specially.